# How to count the number of blanks(not nulls) in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table in which an attribute, status, has the following distinct values:

```
* 
* DDD
* completed
* CRC
* null
* cancelled
```

I want to find out the number of instances where the attribute is blank ( not including nulls). I know a simple count(*) will be give me the count but how do i filter for only the blanks and not include the nulls?

Comment: Only tag your question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the COUNT

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1)
    FROM YourTable 
       WHERE ColumnVal = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If blank means empty string, then you should be able to do:

```
select count(*)
from t
where status = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare with `''` value in where condition

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName=''
```

On top of it it is better to use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` for **MSSQL** to avoid white space

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName))=''
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for!

Comment: this is for ms sql

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from table
where Ltrim(rtrim(status)) = ''
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for!